# If he admitted he will need student pass to stay in USA

Tags: grammar

Whenever there's 'if' sentence case, I'll always confused whether to have 'be' form, or without.

If he admitted he will need student pass to stay in USA.

If he admitted, or if he's admitted the school?

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4):

'He' isn't going to admit anyone, the school is going to admit him - so we need the passive voice.

> If he is admitted, he will need *a* student pass to stay in *the* USA.

Comment: Alternatively, we can discard both the subject *and* the verb from the "conditional" element: ***If admitted,** he will need a student pass*. OP's problem is that he only discarded the verb *(**is**)*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and detailed answer.